# Via Template option is disabled

Tags: pcb-design, altium, eda

When I'm doing the connection, and I want to switch the layers (TOP to BOTTOM via Via), Altium automatically select some default values of Via size. I made my own Via Template, but the "Via Template" listbox is disabled.

[image]

After I create the Via, I must select it again and change the sizes to my template.

[image]

How can I enable the Via Template listbox, or set the default sizes of Via?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you prepare your self some Design-rules where you can set also preferred dimensions of Vias, track width etc. You can than import these same rules in you future projects.
You set the rules for vias through: Design->Rules->Routing->Routing_Vias
And type in the desired dimensions
[image]